# Compass & Sass Deprecation warning

Tags: compass-sass

I just installed and Compass & Sass as described [here](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass).

I got the following warning when I ran `compass watch` for the first time. What exactly does it mean?  What should I do to fix it, do I need to do anything?

```
$ (master) compass watch
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#{$experimental-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6} "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7} "$ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

    write css/styles.css
```

Answer (score 6):

To fix the error message, just change the line 87 from your "_deprecated-support.scss" file to this:

```
    // A debug tool for checking browser support
@mixin debug-support-matrix($experimental: true, $ie: true) {
    @debug '#{"$moz-"}$experimental-support-for-mozilla'
                 '#{"$webkit-"}$experimental-support-for-webkit'
                 '#{"$opera-"}$experimental-support-for-opera'
                 '#{"$microsoft-"}$experimental-support-for-microsoft'
                 '#{"$khtml-"}$experimental-support-for-khtml';
    @debug '#{"$ie6-"}$legacy-support-for-ie6'
                 '#{"$ie7-"}$legacy-support-for-ie7'
                 '#{"$ie8-"}$legacy-support-for-ie8';
}
```

The file can be found at your /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss

Comment: This is messy. How can one override this within the project instead of in a gem?

Comment: Agreed. It seems to be an issue with this version of compass.